# Facebook login stuck with blank page

Tags: php, error-handling, html, facebook-login, login-script

Note: when i got the blank page ,i tried to view source in chrome,then i got the source page of the heading location page

This is a Facebook login application page, the problem is it gets stuck to a blank page,no errors is shown.just a blank page,when i click refresh the page is redirected to the page i want,given in the location .

Insertion is also sometimes done 2-3 time when refresh is done.

How to solve this issue?

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_WARNING | E_NOTICE);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);


include("classes/config.php");
session_start();

    $id =  $_GET['id'];
    $name = $_GET['name'];
    $email = $_GET['email'];
    $email_verified = $_GET['email_verified'];

    $qry1="SELECT * FROM jp_user_master WHERE email='$email'";
    $result1=db_query($qry1);
    $member = mysql_fetch_assoc($result1);
    if($member['fbid'] == NULL){
        $qry2="UPDATE jp_user_master set fbid='$id',email_verified='Yes' WHERE email='$email'";
        $result2=db_query($qry2);
        }   
            $qry3="SELECT * FROM jp_user_master WHERE email='$email' AND fbid='$id'";
            $result3=db_query($qry3);

        //Check whether the query was successful or not
    if($result3) {
        if(db_num_rows($result3) > 0) {

            //Login Successful
            session_regenerate_id();
            $member3 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result3);

            if($member3['email_verified'] == 'Yes'){


                $qry4="SELECT * FROM jp_user_master WHERE email='$email' AND fbid='$id'";
                $result4=db_query($qry4);

                $_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID'] = $member3['ID'];
                $_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_NAME'] = $member3['fname'];
                $_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_EMAIL'] = $member3['email'];


                        flush();
                        header("Location: privilegelist.php");
                        die('should have redirected by now');

/*      //echo $_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID']; exit;
                if(!empty($referer))
                    $redir = "location:".$referer;
                else {
                    $redir = "location:privile`enter code here`gelist.php";
                }
                session_write_close();
                header($redir);
                //exit();*/
            }
}else{



            db_query("INSERT INTO jp_user_master(fbid,fname,email,fblogin,email_verified) VALUES 
                ('$id','$name','$email','$fb','Yes')");
            session_regenerate_id();
            echo session_regenerate_id;
            $ID = db_insert_id();
            if($member3['email_verified'] == 'Yes')
            {

                $_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID'] = $member3['ID'];
                $_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_NAME'] = $member3['name'];
                $_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_EMAIL'] = $member3['email'];

                flush();
                        header("Location: privilegelist.php");
                        die('should have redirected by now');

                /*//echo $_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID']; exit;
                if(!empty($referer))
                    $redir = "location:".$referer;
                else {
                    $redir = "location:privilegelist.php";
                }
                session_write_close();
                header($redir);
                //exit();*/
            }

        }
    }

?>
```

Comment: Have you stepped through the code to see which part is failing? What is your expected result?

Comment: i tried to get results like echoing different areas of the code but there is no result.

Answer (score 0):

Blank page means there're an error on your php script (missing bracket, error on database commands, etc).

if you're hosting that page i suggest for you to see the error_log on the folder inside your hoster